# Sonar - Make DATE_FORMAT as instance variable

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have a rest web service, and below is how i have declared DateFormat as this is the date format i am going to use application wide.

When i did code analysis using SonarLint eclipse plug-in, i got major warning saying "Make **DATE_FORMAT** as instance variable."

```
public class Constants {

    private Constants() {

    }

    public static final DateFormat DATE_TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS");

}
```

Can anyone tell me what issue i might face if i use it this way in my rest API ? 
If i use it as instance variable i will end up declaring it in multiple classes ?

Comment: Having a class to hold constants is anti-pattern. You will end up having such constants in your class which are not related to each other.

Comment: Also, DateFormat is mutable, so it is possible to get errorneous results if used in multthreaded way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Static variable are mostly used for Constants.
Here you have declared static and assigning it instance of `SimpleDateFormat`.
Either make `DATE_TIME_FORMAT`  non-static or assign a constant to this variable.

Better change it to instance variable and use a Sting to do that.
e.g 
`public final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS";`

Answer (score 6):

The triggered rule is S2885:

> **Non-thread-safe fields should not be static**
>   squid:S2885
>   Not all classes in the standard Java library were written to be thread-safe. Using them in a multi-threaded manner is highly likely to cause data problems or exceptions at runtime.
>   This rule raises an issue when an instance of Calendar, DateFormat, javax.xml.xpath.XPath, or javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory is marked static.

Since `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe, it doesn't work well with being shared between threads. You might well end up with wrong formatting of dates.

If you are using Java 8 or above you should use `DateTimeFormatter`, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30106763/1421925). Otherwise, using Joda Time makes sence, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6137576/1421925).

---

As a side note, having a class named `Constants` end let it contain all sorts of static final variables rarely makes sense. Typically you should put each constant where it belongs.

Answer (score 1):

Use joda-time or simply replace variable with method:

```
public static final DateFormat getDateTimeFormat() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS");
}
```